# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list

Tags: sql-server

Let's say there is a `Apartment` table, containing some house entities.  This table  also has a column `ownerid`.

I want to Count and group how many apartments each owner has.

```
select ownerId, Count(*)
from Apartment
group by ownerId, Count(*)
```

Comment: Use `select ownerId, Count(*)
from Apartment
group by ownerId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just:

```
select ownerId, Count(*)
from Apartment
group by ownerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ownerId, Count(ownerId)
from Apartment
group by ownerId
```